# Dart sort a map containing both numeric and alpha keys in descending order

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following map

```
Map<String, String> Dictionary = {
    '37': 'thirty-four',
    '94': 'ninety',
    '91': 'ninety-one',
    '22': 'twenty-one',
    '61': 'sixty-one',
    '9': 'nine',
    '3': 'three',
    '8': 'eight',
    '80': 'eighty',
    '81': 'eighty-one',
    'Ninety-eight': '98',
    'nine-hundred': '900'};
```

I'd like to sort it in ascending order such that the final result is

```
3: three
8: eight
9: nine
22: twenty-two
37: thirty-seven
61: sixty-one
80: eighty
81: eighty-one
91: ninety-one
94: ninety four
Ninety-eight': 98
nine-hundred': 900
```

However the result I'm getting is

```
22: twenty-two
3: three
37: thirty-seven
61: sixty-one
8: eight
80: eighty
81: eighty-one
9: nine
91: ninety-one
94: ninety-four
Ninety-eight: 98
nine-hundred: 900
```

My code for the above results is as follows

```
sortDict(){

    var sortedByKeyMap = Map.fromEntries(
        Dictionary.entries.toList()..sort((e1, e2) => (e1.key).compareTo((e2.key))));

    print(sortedByKeyMap);


  }
```

Any idea on how to convert the numeric string keys to int first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A small trick would help you,

```dart
     var sortedByKeyMap = Map.fromEntries(
        Dictionary.entries.toList()
     ..sort((e1,e2) {
       var key1 = int.tryParse(e1.key);
       var key2 = int.tryParse(e2.key);
       return (key1 != null && key2 != null) ? key1.compareTo(key2) : e1.key.compareTo(e2.key);
     })); 
     
    print(sortedByKeyMap);
```

output:

```js
{
   "3":"three",
   "8":"eight",
   "9":"nine",
   "22":"twenty-one",
   "37":"thirty-four",
   "61":"sixty-one",
   "80":"eighty",
   "81":"eighty-one",
   "91":"ninety-one",
   "94":"ninety",
   "Ninety-eight":98,
   "nine-hundred":900
}
```

Comment: Definitely the solution. If you dont mind could you please ELI5 whats happening in your code?

Comment: The `sort` callback would be better if it just saved the results of `tryParse` instead of parsing each string twice.

Comment: Additionally, if `tryParse` fails, you either should just throw an exception or fall back to the original string comparison.  Unconditionally returning -1 means that an unparsable entry would be treated inconsistently, leading to unexpected results.

Comment: @BlackEyedBeans The important part is just that your `sort` callback needs to call `int.parse` (or `int.tryParse`) on the strings to convert them to integers before performing each comparison.

Comment: @jamesdlin I agreed, if any better solution you can provide, please let me inform <3

Comment: @MeshkatShadik I already told you what to do.  To be explicit, your callback body would be better as: `var key1 = int.tryParse(e1.key); var key2 = int.tryParse(e2.key); return (key1 != null && key2 != null) ? key1.compareTo(key) : e1.key.compareTo(e2.key);`

Comment: @jamesdlin how does that comment skiped my eyes! anyway, I've updated my answer.